# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 3 when trying to get a single row from database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to get a single row from my database, the ID of a note, but I get the error in the title, I should get ID->1 or ID->2 from the Toast I made to check, but I just get the error and the app crashes.
It also wasn't working  before. I added the database code, but before that it was always showing ID->0 on all of the notes.
I have checked other peoples' questions and haven't found a solution to my problem.

The class I am using this on:

```
public class Details extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar5);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Long id = intent.getLongExtra("id", 0);

        DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        Note note = db.getNote(id);


        Toast.makeText(this, "ID -> " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The Database method I am using:

```
public Note getNote(Long ID){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);
        int counter = cursor.getInt(0);

        if(cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        note = new Note(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),
                    cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5));

        return note;
    }
```

Here are the errors I'm getting:

```
Process: com.example.projetolinguagensprogramacao1, PID: 3781
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.projetolinguagensprogramacao1/com.example.projetolinguagensprogramacao1.Details}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 3
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2795)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2873)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1602)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6543)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 3
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:468)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:68)
        at com.example.projetolinguagensprogramacao1.DataBaseHelper.getNote(DataBaseHelper.java:104)
        at com.example.projetolinguagensprogramacao1.Details.onCreate(Details.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7023)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7014)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2748)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2873) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1602) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6543) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

[image]

Edit 1: Changed the code for the Database method and the errors.

Comment: It seems like your table does not contain any rows with ID =1 or ID = 2.

Comment: There are rows with such ID's. Please check the edit I made with a picture from the database entries.

Comment: This is a picture of a database in DB Browser for SQLite. The database that your app uses is inside the device/emulator where you run the app. Did you extract the database to your pc and inspect it? Just to test execute: `SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase(); Cursor cursor = db.query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE, null); int counter = cursor.getInt(0);` and check the value of `counter`.

Comment: Yes I retrieved it from my pc to inspect it. Where do I execute that?

Comment: Execute inside your activity class instead of your code.

Comment: I can't, my activity extends ```AppCompatActivity```, not ```SQLiteOpenHelper```.

Comment: Yes you can. Just replace DATABASE_TABLE with the actual name of the table. Also did you check the value of id after `Long id = intent.getLongExtra("id", 0);`? Is it 1 or 2?

Comment: I edited the code in  the post, now I get a different error. ```CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 3```. Now it sees the amount of notes in the database, but the cursor isn't working correctly.